# How to use dummy class for external API at runtime (configurable)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, inversion-of-control, integration

I need to fetch data from an external API, only accessible via VPN.
The development/test machine will not always be able to connect to the VPN.

The desired behaviour is to use two different implementations (one that calls the actual external API and one that acts as the real thing but returns dummy data). Which implementation to use will be configured via a flag in web.config

I've tried the IoC containers StructureMap and Unity and they both did the job but they only seem to be applicable for MVC, I'm looking for a generic solution that also works for web forms. And also, isn't it a bit overkill to use them for this isolated design problem!?

Is there a design pattern or best practice approach for this particular scenario?

Comment: "they only seem to be applicable for MVC" is not really true... Using IoC container is good approach - you probably should restate your question to figure out why you think it only applies to MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IoC / dependency injection sounds like the correct approach, but you don't necessarily need a container for a simple scenario.  The key is to have classes that depend on the API reference an interface `IAPI`, and pass it the actual implementation `RealAPI` or `FakeAPI`.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly IAPI _api;

    public SomeClass(IAPI api)
    {
        _api = api;
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to switch out the implementation easily by passing a different object to `MyClass`.  In theory, when you're using an IoC approach, you should only need to bind the interface to the implementation once, at the top level of the application.

Comment: Thanks, seems like a good solution. What would be a good way to only bind the interface once at application start without using an ioc container and its bootstrapper for this task?

Answer (score 0):

> isn't it a bit overkill to use them for this isolated design problem!?

They probably are. Those IoC containers only help you when you wrote loosly coupled code. If you didn't design your classes according to the SOLID principles for instance, those frameworks will probably only be in the way. On the other hand, which developer doesn't want to write loosly coupled code? In other words, [IoC container solves a problem you might not have but it's a nice problem to have.](http://kozmic.net/2012/10/23/ioc-container-solves-a-problem-you-might-not-have-but-its-a-nice-problem-to-have/)

> StructureMap and Unity [...] only seem to be applicable for MVC

Those ioc frameworks can be used in any type of application (as long as it is written in loosly coupled way). Some types of applications need a bit more work to plug a framework in, but it's always possible. StructureMap and Unity might only have integration packages for MVC, it's quite easy to use them in ASP.NET Web Forms as well.

> Is there a design pattern or best practice approach for this
>   particular scenario?

What you're looking for is the [Proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) and perhaps the [circuit breaker pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_breaker_design_pattern).

Comment: Thanks, will look into the patterns you mentioned